# Elastic-APM Invalid index name [_license]

Tags: elasticsearch, homebrew, elastic-apm

We are trying to get elastic-apm install (for now on our development systems).

According to Homebrew, we have the latest `elasticsearch-oss` (7.10.2), `kibana-oss` (7.10.2) and today installed `apm-server-oss` (which is at version 7.13.0).
Running a apm-server test output we get:

```
% apm-server test output                
elasticsearch: http://localhost:9200...
  parse url... OK
  connection...
    parse host... OK
    dns lookup... OK
    addresses: ::1, 127.0.0.1
    dial up... OK
  TLS... WARN secure connection disabled
  talk to server... ERROR Connection marked as failed because the onConnect callback failed: could not connect to a compatible version of Elasticsearch: 400 Bad Request: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"invalid_index_name_exception","reason":"Invalid index name [_license], must not start with '_'.","index_uuid":"_na_","index":"_license"}],"type":"invalid_index_name_exception","reason":"Invalid index name [_license], must not start with '_'.","index_uuid":"_na_","index":"_license"},"status":400}
```

Because the documentation on getting APM going is somewhat obtuse, perhaps this is a configuration issue. But how to investigate further?

Is the solution to install an earlier version of apm-server? If so....how to actually do that with homebrew?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when using non-oss versions. Managed to fix this by upgrading ElasticSearch and Kibana to 7.13.2.